# how can i make a post request in http using curl nodejs and including a bson file to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, curl, express

The server is already up, and running, I can make get requests, and some query's, but what I cannot figure out is how to pass a bson file to the curl in order to make a post request:

what I've tried is :

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/bson' -d file.bson http://localhost:3000/dir
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d file.json http://localhost:3000/dir
```

file.bson looks like this:

```
{
 "_id" : 3,
 "User_id" : "Peter",
 "path_video" : "/mnt/1.mp4",
 "var1" : 230,
 "date" : new Date(2013,8,24,19,15),
 "h": 2000,
 "loc": [19.4154248, -99.1661615],
 ...
}
```

The API I'm trying to build looks like this :

```
exports.addEnc = function(req, res) {
var value = req.body;
db.collection('IZP', function(err, collection) {
    collection.insert(value, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
    if (!err){
        console.log('Added:');
        res.send(result[0]);
        }
        });
   });
 };
```

But its a long file and I've tried also, putting the bson like :'{...}' but does not work, any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do with BSON? (BSON is binary, and the example above isn't binary?) And what is your node.js code doing with it when it's POSTed?

Comment: I'm trying to post an entry to a database in mongodb, maybe I'm getting wrong how to make the BSON file, the api I'm doing is:

     exports.addEnc = function(req, res) {
    var value = req.body;
    db.collection('IZP', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(value, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
        if (!err){
            console.log('Added:');
            res.send(result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
    };

Comment: The BSON file looks like JSON. You probably just need to `JSON.parse(req.body)` if the body is a string.

Comment: Its not even JSON, it looks like an object there is a `new Date(2013,8,24,19,15),`

Comment: Won't work with the JSON.parse(...) because of the new Date(2013,8,24,19,15) part. This is the part where it's not a JSON, MongoDB has no trouble doing this in a js script, but the point is I'm trying to send this file via HTTP via API to a mongo server, I'm not sure what you mean with eval? I'm new to the protocol, thanks for the reply!